# Update Quantity on Hand IPP

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to update the quantity on hand for 1500 QuickBooks Online inventory items. I can pull the 1500 products from the store.

1. Can this update be done? I see no quantity on hand object:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/item

1. Can this be done with a batch request:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0300_asynchronous_calls/2_batch_process

If so, how do I perform an update? The same only shows how to create objects.

Comment: Yes, the inventory adjustment is not possible in v2 Quickbooks online. It is supported in v2 quickbooks desktop - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/inventoryadjustment

Answer (score 3):

Quantity On Hand isn't a stand-alone object. The APIs closely mirror the QuickBooks GUI, and in the QuickBooks GUI you use an "Inventory Adjustment" to update quantity on hand.

For QuickBooks for Windows:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/inventoryadjustment

For QuickBooks Online:

- This operation is not supported in the v2 APIs.

Comment: Hi, is it supported in the V3 API for QBO?

Comment: Is it not yet supported in v3, no.